# UIMotionEffectGroup offset glitch

Tags: ios, uiview, frame

At the moment I'm struggling to find a way to remove the offset glitch when I try to change the frame of a UIImageView which has a motionGroup attached to it.

This is the code for adding the motion effect:

```
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *xAxis = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
xAxis.minimumRelativeValue = @(-25.0);
xAxis.maximumRelativeValue = @(25.0);

self.motionGroup = [[UIMotionEffectGroup alloc] init];
self.motionGroup.motionEffects = @[xAxis];

[self.backImageView addMotionEffect:self.motionGroup];
```

now when i need to change the origin I do:

```
[self.backImageView removeMotionEffect:self.motionGroup];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.backImageView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.originalBackImageViewOffset.x + 40;
    self.backImageView.frame = frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.originalBackImageViewOffset = self.backImageView.frame.origin;
    [self.backImageView addMotionEffect:self.motionGroup];
}];
```

this way there is a little glitch if the device is tilted. It appears right after removeMotionEffect: as the imageView transitions to it's original state and only then the frame changes. If the phone isn't tilted you won't even see the glitch (in the simulator).

If you don't remove the animationGroup then there is an even bigger glitch is you tilt the phone during the animation.

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

p.s. I don't have enough reputation to create a tag "UIMotionEffectGroup" or "UIMotionEffect".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the frame, apply a transform, then set the frame when the animation completes, without removing the motion effect:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

    self.backImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(40, 0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    CGRect frame = self.backImageView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.originalBackImageViewOffset.x + 40;
    self.backImageView.frame = frame;
    self.originalBackImageViewOffset = self.backImageView.frame.origin;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Austin, but unfortunatelly the glitch is even bigger that way.